# How to solve this displacement problem

Tags: civil-engineering, structural-analysis

[image]

I have to solve this question, and I've tried multiple things with the angle and displacement but I just cannot figure it out.

I started with a M/EI diagram and i went from there.

Any tips on how to tackle these problems?

Answer (score 3):

I think the aim of this duet of exercises is to make you understand that you can break down problems and superimpose solutions.

## infinite stiffness

In the first case what you do is you have a [simply supported beam with moment](https://mechanicalc.com/reference/beam-deflection-tables) in one support the beam BC.

[image]

$\theta_1$ is the angle at the support. (note that Moment is negative and is equal to 40*1.5)

Since you know the angle and AB does not bend then you only need to calculate the $\theta_1 \cdot 1.5[m]$.

You should find that $\delta\approx 1.6875 mm$

## Finite stiffness

In the finite stiffness case you will have the same deflection due to beam BC, and you need to superimpose the deflection of the beam $AB$.

AB is a cantilever beam with an end load.

[image]

you'd need to add the deflection $\delta_{max} \approx 1.125mm$ to the deflection due to beam BC(=1.6875 mm).